# Is "defease" an English word?

Tags: meaning

I saw people using the word "defeased" in a sentence. I guess the original form of the word should be defease, but I could not find "defease" in any dictionary. Is defease an English word? What does it mean? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the sentence you're referring to.

Comment: defease: to defeat or annul (a contract, deed, etc.). http://www.dictionary.com/browse/defease

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defeased&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefeased%3B%2Cc0) shows an increase in usage of the term "defeased" from the '80s especially with reference to financial assets:

***Defeased Securities***:

> - Securities that have been secured by another asset, such as cash or a cash equivalent, by the debt-issuing firm. Firms that have created defeased securities, which are typically bonds, will have sufficient cash set aside for retirement of the debt upon maturity. (Investopedia)

[Defease](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/defease):

> - to defeat or annul (a contract, deed, etc.). (Dictionary.com)

from ***[defeasance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=defeasance):***

> - early 15c., from Anglo-French defesaunce, Old French desfaisance "undoing, destruction," from desfaire (Modern French défaire) "to undo, destroy" (see defeat (v.)). (Etymonline)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the prompt answer. The sentence was about a retired bond.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps that letter in there is not an f it is an s.  I just looks like an f where the crossing line is not complete.  see [Long S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s#Modern_usage)

For example, see the title page of *Paradise Lost*:

[image: PL]

Comment: That seems unlikely... someone writing with long s would probably also use it for the second s (*deſeaſe*) which could be mistaken for *defeafe,* but not for *defease.* In view of [Josh61's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/318574/77227), this seems to be definitely wrong.

Comment: Even more unlikely with the additional information that the original was about a retired bond.